# SQL query extraction: same row with same id

Tags: sql, oracle

I am bit stuck on the following. The data of the table as follows:

```
  sid   eid  description   returncode    responsemessage   State
    1   T-1                200            OK               Sent 
    1   T-1  Helloworld                                    Processed
```

I cannot use stored procedure, the application only supports a SQL query.

```
select * 
from table 
where eid='T-1' 
  and returncode='200' 
  and returnmessage='OK' 
  and state='Sent'
```

May be something needs to be added here??

Any tips or ideas on how I can achieve this with SQL query?

Update: Oracle Database, I want to retrieve "HelloWorld" from the description column but it should be only retrieved when State=Sent has returncode=200 and responsemessage=ok

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: updated the database.

Comment: Note that text literals are case sensitive - you have state='SENT' in your query and 'Sent' in the database

Comment: Updated the typo error

Comment: :)  Just bear in mind the typo has made it into all the answers submitted so far

Comment: @ChristianPalmer Case sensitivity depends on collation and settings. You cannot say "text literals are case sensitive", they can be, but not necessarily.

Comment: @HoneyBadger - In the context of an Oracle database I'm not sure I agree with you

Comment: @ChristianPalmer Ah, yes, missed Oracle tag. Indeed, oracle is somewhat more strict than other dbms's.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not entirely clear on what you are trying to accomplish, but maybe you meant something like this:

```
select T1.* 
from table  T1
INNER JOIN table T2
        ON  T2.SID = T1.sid
where T1.eid='T-1' 
  and T1.returncode='200' 
  and T1.returnmessage='OK' 
  and T1.state='SENT'
  AND T2.description IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: Updated the description. does the further clarification help?

Comment: Not really to be honest. It sounds like the returncode, responsemessage and State values have to be equated to something else (within an application, perhaps). If you just want to query, this solution should do fine, but it would be good to know how exactly you plan to use this.

Comment: Actually, there is a webservice which creates a new row of data in the database with same eid. I need to somehow first check if the webservice returned the returncode=200 and returnmessage=OK only then I need to return the description with state=Processed.

Comment: What's the primary key of the table? Will you get many rows in the table? Will there always be two rows per event, one with returncodes etc and one with description?

Comment: SID is the primary key. Yes, there can be many rows but I would further add the start date and to date to the query which will reduce the number of result. In a month, there cannot be millions of rows. Yes there will always be two rows per events and one with return code and one with description.

Comment: SID is not the primary key, or your sample data is wrong. If there are only two rows per event, this solution should work fine. Did you try it? Did it work?

Comment: I am testing it. Will keep you posted if your query passes all the test criteria. thanks for your prompt responses.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do this using `exists`:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.description is not null and t.eid = 'T-1' and
      exists (select 1
              from t t2
              where t2.eid = t.eid and t2.returncode = '200' and
                    t2.returnmessage = 'OK' and t2.state = 'SENT' 
             );
```

You might want to include equality on `sid` as well, but that is not clear from the question.